# Lightweight maps webapp (alternative to Google Maps which is too slow)

Tags: web-apps, maps

I often look up an address and check where it is on a map. I was using Google Maps but recently they switched the design and it is slow/unreliable on my 2012 big-screened computer.

Requirements:

- Can be used by specifying the address in the URL, for instance `https://duckmaps.org?address=Azuma 1-11 Tsukuba`
- Free to use
- Maps show up fast, not necessarily full-screen
- Good at finding addresses. Under the hood, it might call the powerful Google Maps geocoding API to get the coordinates.
- Whole world, not just USA.
- A webapp is the best, but a standalone program is OK too if it works on Linux.
- When I spot an interesting spot on a map, I can get its coordinates as text, for instance `35.66262,139.73060`

Tried but rejected:

- [OpenStreetMap](http://www.OpenStreetMap.org): Does not find `Azuma 1-11 Tsukuba`. Any service based on OSM tiles but with a better geoding would be acceptable though.
- [MapQuest](http://www.mapquest.com): Shows the wrong place for `Azuma 1-11 Tsukuba`.

Comment: Jumping in to your question (low-prio to me currently, but I'm interested in the same): are there any services you've already tried (e.g. OSM, MapQuest) – and if so, for what reasons they failed? Not that we get those recommended again ;)

Comment: Or you could contribute to OSM ,-)   Alas, Japanese addresses are some of the most convoluted on earth :-(

Answer (score 3):

I hate to say that [Bing Maps](https://www.bing.com/maps) fits this use case well.

Search URL: [www.bing.com/maps/?v=2&where1=Azuma 1-11 Tsukuba](https://www.bing.com/maps/?v=2&where1=Azuma%201-11%20Tsukuba)

Results are not as precise as Google Maps (does not show the limits of the parcel of land), but it is usable.

Right-clicking anywhere shows the coordinates of the clicked point, easily copy/pastable: 
[image: Bing coordinates]

Drawback: It is still not as lightweight as it could: For some reason the page loads at the country level and reloads and then reloads again at the right zoom level.

Other answers very welcome!

Answer (score 3):

There is one service that fits the bill but is restricted to UK maps.  So although it fails your 'whole world' criterion, it meets all the rest.

[Ordnance Survey OpenData](http://www.ordnancesurvey.co.uk/business-and-government/products/opendata-products.html) has a wide range of abilities to embed and explore maps in a web page.

Free to use, provided you place an acknowledgement on your web page.

Below: The search for 10 Downing Street in London at the system's default settings.

[image: Map based upon 10 Downing Street]

Comment: Would you mind giving the URL for a search on "10 Downing Street London"? Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

There's [HERE](https://www.here.com/), from Nokia.

It has similar features to Google Maps and Bing Maps and I'd say it matches your requirements. It's available as a web app in the web browser but also for pretty much all the mobile platforms around nowadays. Some more detailed features can be found on the [HERE Wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Here_%28Nokia%29).

It perfectly finds `"10 Downing Street London"`:

[image: HERE sample map 1]

Regarding the other address, `"Azuma 1-11 Tsukuba"`, it seems it's able to find something when in Japan, but I have no idea if that's correct or not.

Right-clicking and then left-clicking anywhere on the map enables you to see the coordinates in the address bar, and copy/paste them easily (hence you can also search directly using coordinates). See the address bar in this screenshot:

[image: HERE sample map 2]

In that example the address bar contains:

- The coordinates
- The zoom level
- The map type (for what I've seen it can be ***normal***, ***satellite***, ***terrain***, ***traffic***)

The search syntax is `https://www.here.com/search/<the address>`

Comment: It does not recognize any Japanese address indeed. It only knows the name of the big cities, no further.

Comment: Unfortunately, the technique you describe does not give the coordinates of the point clicked. It gives the coordinates of the nearest address, which can be significantly different. For instance when I organize a picnic Central Park and want to share the exact place where we sit, I don't want the coordinates of the nearest house, I want exact coordinates of the point I clicked.

Comment: It kind of works a bit better if in the overlay top menu you select _Routes_, then the _Walk_ icon, then you right-click and _Set as starting point_. I tried in a golf course and it just added a blue indicator of exactly that spot, with coordinates in the address bar. Basically it looks like you need to have the _Walk_ function on to be able to pinpoint locations freely. Perhaps with a HERE mobile app there's a way to get and share locations more easily, but I' haven’t' tried.